# Run commands on HTML files if CSS or JS update

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following makefile that is attempting to run some commands on HTML files, if any  of the .CSS or .JS files change.

The first .HTM file "works", the rule is run, but the others show "up to date" (they are not).

```
CSS_Files = $(wildcard wwwroot/assets/css/*.css)
JS_Files = $(wildcard wwwroot/assets/js/*.js)
HTML_Files = $(wildcard wwwroot/t*.htm wwwroot/pw*.html) 

all : $(HTML_Files)

$(HTML_Files) : $(CSS_Files) $(JS_Files)
    @echo Build '$(@F)' - '$(%F)' 
    -@attrib -r $@
    @hashinclude $@ -inplace -hvonly
```

Here's the output

```
e:\code\project>make
Build 'template.htm' - ''
/assets/js/appsvc.js?hv=8a52d1d0
wwwroot\template.htm created. Files Updated: 1. Total: 10
Build 'terminal_logon.htm' - ''
wwwroot/terminal_logon.htm is up to date.
Build 'pwlookup.html' - ''
wwwroot/pwlookup.html is up to date.
Build 'pwreset.html' - ''
wwwroot/pwreset.html is up to date.
```

In this case a appsvc.js was updated, and template.htm was "built".  However the other .HTML files were considered as "up to date", but they need to be re-built too.

Comment: Those messages about "up to date" are not being printed by make, they must be printed by `hashinclude` which I don't know what that is.  But this doesn't seem to be, based on your description here, a problem with GNU make.  it is running your commands, as you can see because the `Build '...'` line is printed.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful.  hashinclude is a utility I made to add cache-busting hash values to CSS / JS includes.  I'll test with just "echo"

Comment: I _strongly_ recommend you do not add `@` to your recipe, except maybe the `echo` command.  If you do want to add it, at least wait until your makefile is fully working before you do.  Else, you're hiding critical output that can help you debug.  It's like redirecting all your output to `/dev/null` then trying to figure out what's wrong with the program.

Comment: Yeah, hiding the command  with @ is what got me in trouble.  Thanks for your help.  People like you make this site great.